# Magento disabling multiple days in calender

Tags: magento

I want to disable mulitple days in magento calendar. How ever i can disable a single day. using the following code. But I want to disbale multiple days in a calendar, so the question is how the disableFunc function return multiple days which will be disabled.

Follwing is the code`<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
 Calendar.setup({
    inputField : '_dob',
    ifFormat : '%m/%e/%y',
    button : '_dob_trig',
    align : 'Bl',
    disableFunc: function(date) {
        return date.getDay() === 1; // Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, and so on
    },
    singleClick : true
});
//]]>
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

/app/code/local/Varien/Data/Form/Element/date.php

Create a .php file in following above location.  The below code disables dates two weeks in advance and advances the calendar to the soonest available date.  Hope this helps.  Not the cleanest way to accomplish in my opinion, but it works.

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category   Varien
 * @package    Varien_Data
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2008 Irubin Consulting Inc. DBA Varien (http://www.varien.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * Varien data selector form element
 *
 * @category   Varien
 * @package    Varien_Data
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Varien_Data_Form_Element_Date extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Output the input field and assign calendar instance to it.
     * In order to output the date:
     * - the value must be instantiated (Zend_Date)
     * - output format must be set (compatible with Zend_Date)
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getElementHtml()
    {
        $this->addClass('input-text');

        $html = sprintf(
            '<input name="%s" id="%s" value="%s" %s style="width:110px !important;" />'
            .' <img src="%s" alt="" class="v-middle" id="%s_trig" title="%s" style="%s" />',
            $this->getName(), $this->getHtmlId(), $this->_escape($this->getValue()), $this->serialize($this->getHtmlAttributes()),
            $this->getImage(), $this->getHtmlId(), 'Select Date', ($this->getDisabled() ? 'display:none;' : '')
        );
        $outputFormat = $this->getFormat();
        if (empty($outputFormat)) {
            throw new Exception('Output format is not specified. Please, specify "format" key in constructor, or set it using setFormat().');
        }
        $displayFormat = Varien_Date::convertZendToStrFtime($outputFormat, true, (bool)$this->getTime());

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()) {
            $html .= sprintf('
                <script type="text/javascript">
                //<![CDATA[
                    Calendar.setup({
                        inputField: "%s",
                        ifFormat: "%s",
                        showsTime: %s,
                        button: "%s_trig",
                        align: "Bl",
                        singleClick : true,
                        weekNumbers: false
                    });
                //]]>
                </script>',

                $this->getHtmlId(), $displayFormat,
                $this->getTime() ? 'true' : 'false', $this->getHtmlId()
            );
        } else {
            $html .= sprintf('
                <script type="text/javascript">
                //<![CDATA[
                    // Get current date plus two weeks
                    var twoWeeks = new Date(+new Date() + (14 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                    Calendar.setup({
                        inputField: "%s",
                        ifFormat: "%s",
                        showsTime: %s,
                        button: "%s_trig",
                        align: "Bl",
                        singleClick : true,
                        weekNumbers: false,
                        date: twoWeeks,
                        disableFunc: function(date) {
                            // Disable dates with previous years
                            if (date.getFullYear() < twoWeeks.getFullYear()) {
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                // Disable dates with same year but previous months
                                if(date.getFullYear() === twoWeeks.getFullYear()) {
                                    if (date.getMonth() < twoWeeks.getMonth()) {
                                        return true;
                                    } else {
                                        // Disable dates with the same month but previous dates
                                        if (date.getMonth() === twoWeeks.getMonth()) {
                                            if(date.getDate() < twoWeeks.getDate()) {
                                                return true;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                //]]>
                </script>',

                $this->getHtmlId(), $displayFormat,
                $this->getTime() ? 'true' : 'false', $this->getHtmlId()
            );
        }

        $html .= $this->getAfterElementHtml();

        return $html;
    }
}
```